# DOM manipulation does not work

Tags: jquery

Yes I know, this title isn't really helpfull but this is the exact problem. For some reason (I don't know), I can't manipulate my HTML in the *beforeSend* Function of my AJAX-Request.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="right">
    <span id="observer-eye" original-title="Observe this Summoner" data-id="2">
        <img alt="" src="/lolreports/img/icons/observer_eye.png">
    </span>
</div>
```

And this is the AJAX-Request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: webroot + 'summoners/observe',
    data: 'data[Summoner][id]=' + id,
    beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
        $(this).parent().empty();
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.status == 'success') {
            $(this).find('img').attr("src", webroot + 'img/icons/observed_eye.png"');
        }
    }
});
```

My goal is to put an ajax-loader.gif inside the -Tag which I wanted to do with $(this).find('img').attr("src", webroot + 'img/icons/ajax-loader.gif"'); - Nothing happened. I tested many ways to manipulate the image or the span, but nothing happens. I wondered if *beforeSend* gets ever executed, which I tested with an *alert()*. It worked. But no DOM manipulation.

I have no idea where to search, I hope you can help me.

Comment: `$(this)` in your `beforeSend` handler refers not to what you think. Check it with `console.log(this);`

Comment: what triggers this AJAX call? can you put?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `$(this)` as it doesn't rightly reference your intended element. There are of course many ways to do this, try this

```
$("#observer-eye").find('img').attr("src", webroot + 'img/icons/observed_eye.png"');
```

For the beforesend, don't use `$(this)`, do this instead

```
$('the-intended-selector').parent.empty()
```

Comment: I should have found this by myslef :P But thanks, thats the solution!